# Measures of subsets of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $S$ is a Lebesgue measurable set on the real line with positive measure $s$. It seems natural to guess the following: for any $m \in [0,s]$, there is a subset $S' \subset S$ such that the Lebesgue measure of $S'$ is $m$. I'm failing to come up with a proof though.

Comment: An idea: Let $f(x) = m((-x,x) \cap S)$. Show that $f$ is continous. What is $f(0)$? What is $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$? Apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m=0$ or $m=s$ then this is obvious. Now consider $m\in (0,s)$. Consider $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x 1_{S} d\mu=\mu(S\cap (-\infty, x))$. If you can prove that $F$ is continuous, your claim would follow from the intermediate value theorem. (Note that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=s$ by continuity from above/below)

Answer (score 0):

Overkill answer:  If $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure, $\nu:A\mapsto \lambda(A\cap A)$ is an atomless measure, hence an atomless vector measure, and hence its range $L$  is closed and convex, by [Lyapunov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Lyapunov's_theorem).  Since $\nu(\phi)=0$ and $\nu(\mathbb R)=s$, we know $L=[0,s]$, and hence for each $m\in [0,s]$ there exists an $A\subset S$ with $\nu(A)=m$.